# Why does rejectionhandled not trigger(get captured) if I console.log the unhandledrejection event with chrome/opera browser console open?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, promise

I noticed an unexpected behaviour with Promises today. If you run the following example with js code inline in script tag in your index.html, you will see both `unhandledrejection` and `rejectionhandled` events are fired:

```
"use strict";

var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Prom 1 executed");
    reject("Rejected");
  }, 1000);
});

console.log("Before Prom 1");

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function(e) {
  console.log("Handled Rejection", e);
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
  console.log("unhandledrejection", "e");
  setTimeout(function() {
    prom1.then(null, function(err) {
      console.log("Caught error");
    });
  }, 1000);

});
```

Now all I am gonna do is two things,

1. Keep the chrome/opera browser **console open**.
2. Log the `unhandledrejection` event itself. As a side effect, it causes the `rejectionhandled` event to not fire and browser throws error the console, thinking, rejection was never handled.

---

```
"use strict";

var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Prom 1 executed");
    reject("Rejected");
  }, 1000);
});

console.log("Before Prom 1");

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function(e) {
  console.log("Handled Rejection", "e"); // never logs ???
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
  console.log("unhandledrejection", e); // "e" changed to actual event
  setTimeout(function() {
    prom1.then(null, function(err) {
      console.log("Caught error");
    });
  }, 1000);

});
```

Why is that and when you keep console closed on page load and open later you'd see `rejectionhandled` fire and log `Handled Rejection e`?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your help mate, I'll leave things as they are for the moment, bit overboard for my skill level yet to deal with browser documentations.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by Chrome's dev-tools and can probably be considered a bug.
I did report it at https://crbug.com/1395719.

The culprit is [this CL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/af03c93bda086b73ca5fe4acedf7d0556d69a886), where they decided that property accessors pointing to rejected `Promise` objects should [mark them as handled](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/3110610/2/src/inspector/value-mirror.cc#1301).

Reading both https://crbug.com/1076820 and https://crbug.com/1199247 it's not quite clear why they made this choice, hopefully they'll be able to clarify if they did consider HTML's *rejectionhandled* event when they did so, or if you indeed found a "bug".

For the time being, if this is an issue for you, you can kind of temper the bug by overriding the `.promise` accessor of the `PromiseRejectionEvent` object before it gets logged.

```js
const prom1 = Promise.reject(null);
let handled = false;

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", (e) => {
  handled = true;
  console.log("[Success]: The rejectionhandled event fired as expected");
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (e) => {
  // workaround CRBUG 1395719
  Object.defineProperty(e, "promise", { value: e.promise });
  console.log("unhandledrejection", e);
  setTimeout(() => {
    prom1.then(null, (err) => {
      // handling event
      console.log("Handling rejected Promise");
    });
  }, 0);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!handled) {
      console.log("[Failure]: The rejectionhandled event didn't fire");
    }
  }, 10);
});
```

```html
Try running this snippet with or without the dev-tools open.
```